# Why message loop doesn't block the GUI in windows app but does in Qt?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, winapi, loops

I'm working on a program using Qt, and some of my code is based on Windows samples. The problem I'm having, and something I don't quite understand is how the same code will block my Qt GUI while it will work totally fine in a windows app.

Here's an example. I have a program which gets some data from the camera, does some processing on it, then displays it on the screen. In Windows sample there's something like this:

```
// Create an event with these self-explanatory parameters
// This event signals when the next frame is ready to process
HANDLE frameEvent  = CreateEvent(nullptr, TRUE, FALSE, nullptr)

// Now run a while loop which magically doesn't block
HANDLE hEvents[1];

while (WM_QUIT != msg.message)
{
  hEvents[0] = frameEvent;

  DWORD dwEvent = MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(1, hEvents, FALSE, INFINITE, QS_ALLINPUT);

  // If we have our event run some processing
  if (WAIT_OBJECT_0 == dwEvent)
  {
    update();
  }
  // Else handle input or whatever
}
```

The update function looks something like this:

```
if (WAIT_OBJECT_0 = WaitForSingleObject(frameEvent, 0)
{
  getTheFrame();
  processTheFrame();
  drawTheFrame();
}
```

If I try to implement it the same way in Qt everything will freeze and the while loop will just run forever. The solution I've got is to run the loop in separate thread (QThread) and emit a signal when new frame is ready, like this:

```
void Worker::run()
{
    running_ = true;

    while (running_)
    {
        if (WaitForSingleObject(frameEvent, 0) == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
        {
            emit signalFrame();
        }

        // This is necessary or it will still freeze!
        usleep(15);
    }
}
```

The signal is then connected to a slot which does similar job to the `Update()` method from the windows sample.

Now, this works fine, but only as long as processing a single frame can be done before the next frame is available.

As my processing went more complex and is slower then camera framerate, the program just stops responding. The exact same code in the windows sample still works fine, the framerate just drops, but everything is drawn and the GUI remains responsive.

Could someone explain what is going on, and what may be a possible solution?

Comment: You in effect replaced the Qt message loop, messages are now dispatched by MWFMO.  I don't know what the Qt's message loop looks like but it is bound to be non-standard.  So mishaps are not unlikely.  Instead of emitting a signal, use PostMessage so the frame retrieval code still runs on the main thread.  And use an event to signal the thread to resume looping once the frame is retrieved.

Comment: The frame retrieval code does run in the main thread. The worker thread on checks for the even periodically and signals when new frame is ready to be retrieved. I'm not sure if Qt's message loop is in fact being replaced. The problem comes from the fact that camera produces 30 frames per seconds, but I can only process, say 10. So before I'm done processing a frame there are already several frames available. Pausing the loops does seem like a simple solution (is it how it works on Windows? Are the frames just dropped while processing takes place?). I managed to make it work by using

Comment: `QThread::blockSignals()`. So it's now something like `onNewFrameReady() { worker.blockSignals(true); doProcessing(); worker.blockSignals(false); }. I guess using signals to pause and then resume the loop would have the same effect. If you'd be so kind to comment on that as an answer I'll accept that as solution.

Answer (score 3):

The Win32 version calls [`MsgWaitForMultipleObjects`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684242.aspx).  As its name should imply, it waits for either the specified objects to be signaled *or* for a window message (and since it's called with `QS_ALLINPUT`, *any* window message).  Presumably the code also dispatches the window message afterward.

Your version calls [`WaitForSingleObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032.aspx).  As its name should imply, it waits on *only* the specified object.  It won't unblock itself on window messages.

Comment: You misunderstood the question.  He used WFSO in a *thread* after he could not get MWFMO going.  Which was a correct use of WFSO.

Comment: Yes, this is not really the issue. I could probably replace WFSO in the thread with MWFMO and the problem would remain.

Comment: @HansPassant But the question didn't explain *why* she uses WFSO instead of MWFMO.  The comment "Now run a while loop which magically doesn't block" suggested to me that she didn't understand why another thread was necessary in her version.  And the statement "If I try to implement it the same way in Qt everything will freeze and the while loop will just run forever." seems false since she did not implement it "the same way".

Comment: @Marian Why "probably"?  Have you not actually tried using MWFMO?  If so, why not?

Comment: @Marian Okay, you should mention that in the question then. (And sorry, I usually associate "Marian" with "Maid Marian" from Robin Hood.)